# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm doing a school project. It is a basically easy exercise in which I should create 3 tables. I've decided to use Python and, following [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_db.asp), I wrote the following code:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'admin',
    passwd = 'admin',
    database = 'primo'
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE primo")
```

When I try to execute it, it returns:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

I'd like to run it locally; if i change 'localhost' with '127.0.01' an error with ports shows up (however I read I've better to use 'localhost')

Comment: You have not started MySQL or your Firewall is getting in the way

Comment: Does your HOSTS file have these 2 lines `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost`

Comment: Or maybe your database is not listening on the standard port 3306